# Java Swing Scroll through drawing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, paintcomponent

Im trying to add a JScrollpane to my JPanel. The problem is that the scrollpane doesn't recognize that my drawing is outside the frame. So how do I add the JScrollpane correctly?

Main class:

```
public MainFrame() extends JFrame{

public MainFrame() {

        Container container = getContentPane(); 
        container(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(new JScrollPane(new Drawing()));

        setSize(1280,720);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Drawing class:

```
public class Drawing() extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.drawLine(10, 100, 30000, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve], are you calling `pack()`? Are you extending `JFrame`? It's not a good idea: See [extends JFrame vs calling it inside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)

Comment: My MainFrame extends JFrame and my Drawing class extends JPanel.  I'm not calling pack().

Comment: Did you read both links? A MCVE is needed, so we can help you faster and better

Comment: i extended the code, which reproduces my problem

Comment: Most probably, the problem is that your `Drawing` panel doesn't have the same size as your drawing `30000X10`. You'll have to specifically set its size, it won't be set automatically based on what you draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code, let's step through each of them:

1. You're extending `JFrame`, and you should avoid it, see: [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program) for more information about it. You're actually not changing its behavior so it's not needed to extend it.
2. For your `JScrollPane` to show the whole line, you need to change your window's size to be the same size of your line (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415897/2180785) by @MadProgrammer).
3. Related to point 2, avoid the use of `setSize(...)` and instead override `getPreferredSize()`: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more information
4. You forgot to call `super.paintComponent(...)` method in your `paintComponent()` method.
5. Related to points 2, 3, you need to call `pack()` so Swing calculates the best preferred size for your component.

See this example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LongDraw {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Drawing drawing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LongDraw()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        drawing = new Drawing();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(drawing);

        frame.add(scroll);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class Drawing extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawLine(10, 100, 3000, 10);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(3000, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces something similar to this:

[image]